How to upgrade Cassandra 3.11.3 to 4.0.0?
I am supposed to upgrade my Cassandra version to 4.0.0 but whenever I am doing so I am getting the many issues like these:
error: error: cannot access TypeCodec,
error: cannot find symbol

And it is not able to find my autowired and injected mocks in the repo. On upgrading the version I am left with so many similar issues that it seems impossible to upgrade the same.
I tried to solve the issue by downgrading achilles-core but that is also not working for me.
Sharing the smaller version of POM, can somebody please help me to upgrage the version without getting many issues? Also my project is using spring version 4.0.
<dependency>
        <groupId>info.archinnov</groupId>
        <artifactId>achilles-core</artifactId>
        <version>${achilles.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>


Is there a reason you would use just 4.0.0 on the Java driver?  4.17 is released https://github.com/apache/cassandra-java-driver
